# Active navbar with css animation

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations, navbar, onscroll

i have trouble with a navbar.

It's a 3D rotating navbar. It's fixed on the left. Visually, it's meant to be stacked cardbox boxes. Each carbox box is a LI element. When mouse is over there is a rotation with an after element and a css animation displaying the name of the section in the after element within a content property.

For now I haven't managed to put the anchor link in the content property, I now it's not directly possible and I think it's a part of the problem.

I'd like to make this navbar active, meaning when scrolling on a section, the cardbox box automatically animate showing the after element. When skipping to another section inactivate the current after element and active the new one.

I've opened a codepen https://codepen.io/agence_mibe/pen/OJvbYLd

I'm not good with javascript, learning by myself, sorry if there is absurdity in the code.

Help would be very very much appreciated,

(when inserting code on the snippet I've seen an error on javascript (!))

Frédéric

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

  //active navigation

  function onScroll(event) {
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('nav a').each(function() {
      var currLink = $(this);
      var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
      if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
        $('nav ul li').removeClass("after");
        currLink.addClass("after");
      } else {
        currLink.removeClass("after");
      }
    });
  }


  //smoothscroll
  $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(document).off("scroll");

    $('li').each(function() {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    })
    $(this).addClass('active');

    var target = this.hash,
      menu = target;
    $target = $(target);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
      'scrollTop': $target.offset().top + 2
    }, 500, 'swing', function() {
      window.location.hash = target;
      $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
nav {
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
  top: 25%;
  left: 0;
  background: transparent;
  z-index: 1;
}

nav ul {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: bebas-neue, sans-serif;
}

nav ul li {
  position: relative;
  width: 70px;
  height: 90px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #B7B2A7;
  border: .5px solid #7A7262;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: all .4s ease-out;
}

nav ul li:after {
  position: absolute;
  background: #B7B2A7;
  border: .5px solid #7A7262;
  color: #7A7262;
  top: 0;
  left: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: .5;
  transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(90deg);
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  transition: all .4s ease-out;
  font-size: 10px;
}

nav ul li:nth-child(1):after {
  content: "hero";
  line-height: 88px;
}

nav ul li:nth-child(2):after {
  content: "activity";
  line-height: 88px;
}

nav ul li:nth-child(3):after {
  content: "stock";
  line-height: 88px;
}

nav ul li:nth-child(4):after {
  content: "contact";
  line-height: 88px;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  transform: translateX(-70px);
}

nav ul li:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(0deg) scale(1);
}

nav ul li:active {
  transform: translateX(-70px);
}

nav ul li:active:after {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(0deg) scale(1);
}

nav ul li>div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 25px 0;
  background: transparent;
}

nav ul li div {
  position: relative;
}

.navimg {
  height: auto;
  width: 90%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2px;
  left: 4px;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 70px;
}

.subcontent {
  position: relative;
  width: 95%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#welcomehero"><img class="navimg" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/black-friday-5-cut-line/468/02-barcode-512.png"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#activity"><img class="navimg" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/black-friday-5-cut-line/468/02-barcode-512.png"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#stock"><img class="navimg" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/black-friday-5-cut-line/468/02-barcode-512.png"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#contact"><img class="navimg" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/black-friday-5-cut-line/468/02-barcode-512.png"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<section id="welcomehero">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="subcontent">
      <div style="text-align: center;">
        <br><br>
        <h1>welcomehero</h1><br><br>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">
          <div class="col-sm ">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
            in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
            elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
            esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
            ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
            Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
            mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
            commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum
            dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
            in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
            elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
            esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
            in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
            elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
            esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
            ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
            Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim
            ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="activity">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="subcontent">
      <div style="text-align: center;">
        <br><br>
        <h1>activity</h1><br><br>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">
          <div class="col-sm ">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
            in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
            elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
            esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
            ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
     itation
            ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
            mollit anim id est laborum.
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
rum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
            ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
            Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim
            ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="stock">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="subcontent">
      <div style="text-align: center;">
        <br><br>
        <h1>stock</h1>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incidi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
        dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
        et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
        sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa
        qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
        dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
        et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
        sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa
        qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="contact">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="subcontent">
      <div style="text-align: center;">
        <br><br>
        <h1>contact.</h1><br><br>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">
          <div class="col-sm ">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incidi dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
            ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
            mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, s
            esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
           
            esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
         
            Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim
            ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
            ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
            mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
            commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum
            dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do                 in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
            elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
            esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thx, forgot the jquery !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no class called `after`,

Change this:

```
nav ul li:active {
  transform: translateX(-70px);
}

nav ul li:active:after {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(0deg) scale(1);
}
```

to This:

```
.active {
  transform: translateX(-70px);
}

.active:after {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(0deg) scale(1);
}
```

The jQuery part is a little tricky, you were trying to change the class of `a`, but the element needed the change is the `li`, so I added `.parent()` to the code.

So, change JS from this:

```
$(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

  //active navigation

  function onScroll(event) {
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('nav a').each(function() {
      var currLink = $(this);
      var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
      if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
        $('nav ul li').removeClass("after");
        currLink.addClass("after");
      } else {
        currLink.removeClass("after");
      }
    });
  }
```

to this:

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('nav a').each(function() {
      var currLink = $(this);
      var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
      if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
        $('nav ul li').removeClass("active");
        currLink.parent().addClass("active");
      } else {
        currLink.parent().removeClass("active");
      }
    });
  })
```

Comment: Thank you very much !

« The jQuery part is a little tricky, you were trying to change the class of a, but the element needed the change is the li, ».Yes I tried with the li element but never managed to make the change.

Comment: @MIBE Glad to help. Please accept the answer if the problem solved.